# cursor not going to end of line in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I installed Ubuntu recently and fiddled around with profile preferences in terminal. Now when I edit in vim, the cursor doesn't go to the end of a line using navigation keys (In normal mode. '$' doesn't work either). However, it does show itself correctly in insert mode. This is merely a nuisance, but I'd rather be not having it. How to correct this?

Comment: Sounds highly unlikely. Changing profile preferences would not arbitrarily change a single TUI app.

Comment: In normal mode, what does `$` do? Does `$` print when you type it in the terminal (not in vim)? What preferences did you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior in vim. The cursor will only go to the last character unless in insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualedit permits the cursor to move past the end of line.  Try `:set ve+=all` or `:set ve+=onemore`.  For more information see:
`:h ve`.  These settings can be made default by adding corresponding command without `:` to your ~/.vimrc file.

Comment: this is works for me, I am adding `set ve+=onemore` to .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my vimrc and it seems to work.

```
set selection=exclusive
" allows cursor to go to the end of line with g$
set virtualedit+=onemore
noremap $ g$
" Remap VIM 1 to first non-blank character and 2 to the last non-blank character
nnoremap 1 ^
nnoremap 2 g$
" mapping for <End>
map <Esc>[4~ g$
```